# Javascript appendChild if div not exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, appendchild

i've working in a big project, and that i want is

```
if div 1 not contain div 2 child{

div1.appendChild(div2)

}
```

But, i'm getting problem to solve this

My code

```
<script>
dc = document.createElement("div");
dc.className = "doctor_card doctor-"+o+" hidden";
dcc.appendChild(dc);
</script>
```

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
var className = "doctor_card doctor-"+o+" hidden";

if (dcc.getElementsByClassName(className).length == 0) {
    dc = document.createElement("div");
    dc.className = className;
    dcc.appendChild(dc);
}
</script>
```

Comment: OMGGGGGGG! thanks for advice bro, fully worked were! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dcc = document.getElementsByClassName('parentclass')[0];
if (!dcc.contains(dc)) {
 dcc.appendChild(dc);
}
```

You can use above code if u really want to use pure javascript.